# Indent, Font of headlines

Tags: fonts, indentation, line-spacing

1. I need to set an indent which must be equal to 1.27 cm, but, actually, I have no indent at the first line after title. How can I add it at the beginning of EVERY LINE, including the first one?
2. Font of headlines must have bold type with size 16. Besides, line-to-line spacing must be 1.5 everywhere. Instead of it, I have very large line-to-line spacing between any text and headlines by default

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt ]{report}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,mathtext,cite,enumerate,float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{parallel,enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{par}{\par}
\captionsetup{labelsep=par,justification=centering}
\graphicspath{{images/}}


\newcommand\tablecaption[1]{
\captionsetup{labelsep=par,justification=centering}
\caption{#1}
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm}
\geometry{right=1cm}
\geometry{top=2cm}
\geometry{bottom=2cm}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}
```

Why is there a very big indent?

[image]

As for the indent, I want to fix this problem:

[image]

Comment: It's a good practise to ask separate. To 1.) `usepackage{indentfirst}` -- 2.) Depends on the document class. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: "Why is there a very big indent?" Do you mean the gap between the headlines? That would even be a third question and one impossible to answer without a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to set an indent which must be equal to 1.27 cm, but, actually, I have no indent at the first line after title. How can I add it at the beginning of EVERY LINE, including the first one?

The KOMAscript bundle has an environment called »addmargin«. If you use a KOMAscript class (scr-book/reprt/artcl), you got it already, otherwise load the package `scrextend`.

The code is:

```
\begin{addmargin}[1.27cm]{0pt}
Your text t t t t . . .
\end{addmargin}
```

Besides that: There is a new version of KOMAscript and the most important thing is: There is a complete, new english manual! Thinking about that, I will make a blogpost of this.

Comment: The OP was missing the "indent at the first line after title" (heading?), so I'd rather think `\indent Some text` or `\usepackage{indentfirst}` is the solution.

Comment: @lockstep Well, I've understood that he'd like to indent every line. Let's wait for his answer.

Comment: lockstep, you suggestion is correct, thanks